# RestKit: parse single dimensional array from JSON object array

Tags: objective-c, json, restkit

I have a key-value based JSON array like this:

```
[
    {"key": "firstKey", "value": "firstValue"}, 
    {"key": "secondKey", "value": "secondValue"}
]
```

And I need to convert this to a single dimensional array, for instance if I'm only interested in the "value" property of the JSON, like this:

```
["firstValue", "secondValue"]
```

What kind of an object mapping must I use to achieve this?

I tried setting the `toKeyPath` to nil, hoping it would assign the parsed value directly to my receiving object (while reading a single dimensional array, the `fromKeyPath` is set to nil), but that didn't happen.

Comment: Well, there are fancy-dancy things you can do, but it's simpler, easier to understand, and about as fast to just write the obvious loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSError* error;
NSMutableArray* resultArray = [NSMutableArray array];
NSArray* jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization objectWithData:receivedJSONData options:nil error:&error];
if (jsonArray == nil) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error); // error occurred
}
else {
    for (NSDictionary* jsonDict in jsonArray) {
        [resultArray addObject: jsonDict[@"value"]];
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem here is that the JSON example I gave is only part of a larger JSON body. I need to use RestKit to parse the rest of it.
How can I selectively extract this part of the whole JSON?

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track with the nil key path mapping (assuming you want a different object for each of the values in the simple array), but you need to combine it with a response descriptor which drills into the data to extract a simple array using its key path.

So, the mapping has a nil key path and the response descriptor has a `XXX.value` key path (where XXX is the path to get to the array containing these objects).